# Image auto resize

Tags: images

I can't figure out why does my image resize by itself when I upload it as a background of a section by adding in a "300x195" behind my data-bg-url.

Eg.
data-bg-url="https://bountie.cc/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/DG3_9924-300x195.jpg"

My site is: https://bountie.cc/events-space-rental/

I'm using Fusion Builder as my editor. This only happened to the newly replaced image for the sections "VIP Gaming Room"(New) vs "Console Corner"(Old)

Please advice. :(

[image]